# is there a working color picker control in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, color-picker

I need a color picker control in my Windows Phone 7 project. I've tried the controls in [Silverlight Contrib](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/) but I cannot make it work in WP7 project. There is even [a discussion with the same question](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/discussions/242187) but there's no replies. How can I use the control? Or is there a substitute I can use?

Comment: does the below work for you? if so, you can select the hollow checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how many colors you need, then this blog provides a page like the "Accent" one in settings - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/17/customizing-picker-box-dialog.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While not a pre-built control, per se, Petzold has a pretty good write-up on using Items controls and uses colors as one of his main examples.

You can find these in [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html), Chapter 17, sections 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [RadPickerBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/pickerbox.aspx) from telerik. Its works well and can probably accomplish what your trying to do. I think right now there actually giving a free license for the first 500 developers or something. I've already used it and had no issues.

But if you don't want to go commercial ^^^Stuart's source is pretty good.